# How can I split a word into bi-grams, including repeated ones?

Tags: r, text-processing

I am trying to split a word into bi-grams. I am using the `qlcMatrix` package, but it only returns distinct bi-grams. For example, for the word `"detected"`, it only returns `"te"` once.
This is the command I use

```
test_domain <- c("detected")
library("qlcMatrix", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
bigram1 <- splitStrings(test_domain, sep = "", bigrams = TRUE, left.boundary = "", right.boundary = "")$bigrams
```

and this is the result I get:

```
bigram1
# [1] "ec" "ed" "de" "te" "ct" "et"
```

Comment: The `$bigrams` returns "A vector will all unique bigrams", so it's normal that there are no duplicates

Comment: Indeed. So I guess this package won't do the trick...? I am trying not to use packages in general but I 've been stack (pun intended) for a while now.

Comment: To be clear, you want to have this : `"de" "et" "te" "ec" "ct" "te" "ed"` ?

Comment: Exactly. Not only the distinct bi-grams.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another way to do it with base `R` is to use `mapply` and `substr`:

```
nc <- nchar("detected")
mapply(function(x, y){substr("detected", x, y)}, x=1:(nc-1), y=2:nc)
# [1] "de" "et" "te" "ec" "ct" "te" "ed"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that without packages:

```
test_domain <- c("detected")
temp <- strsplit(test_domain ,'')[[1]]
sapply(1:(length(temp)-1), function(x){paste(temp[x:(x+1)], collapse='')})
# [1] "de" "et" "te" "ec" "ct" "te" "ed"
```