# Split string in sliding window in a dataframe

Tags: r, string, split, character

[I have previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315999/split-string-each-x-characters-in-dataframe) for a method to split a string each 3 characters and save the results in a dataframe. Now I want to do the same thing but instead in a sliding window of size `n`.

**This question differs from [the marked duplicate one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083585/how-can-i-split-a-word-into-bi-grams-including-repeated-ones) as the results here should be outputed in a dataframe. The `mapply` function given would require quite some extra work to combine it in a new dataframe and to add the positions as column names as explained at the [top of my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315999/split-string-each-x-characters-in-dataframe/56321910#56321910) .**

**Example data**

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:2, seq = c('ABCDEF', 'XYZZZY'))
```

Looks like this:

```
  id    seq
1  1 ABCDEF
2  2 XYZZZY
```

**Splitting on every third character with a window size of `n = 1`**

```
id  1   2   3   4
1   ABC BCD CDE DEF
2   XYZ YZZ ZZZ ZZY
```

I tried to do this using the `seperate` function as answered on my previous post however as far as I can find this can only split on fixed split points rather than on a range.

---

Comment: This partially does the job. Maybe you can tweak it with `rapply`: `lapply(seq_along(df$seq),function(x) substring(df$seq,x,x+2))`.

Comment: `library(zoo); with(df, data.frame(id, t(sapply(strsplit(as.character(seq), ""), rollapplyr, 3, paste, collapse = "")), check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))`

Comment: That worked fine! thankyou @G.Grothendieck

Comment: ```cbind(df , t(data.frame(lapply(df[,2] , function(dfword){mapply(function(x, y){substr(dfword, x, y)}, x=1:(nc-2), y=3:nc)}),row.names = NULL)))```